# Scheduler on Azure

Tags: azure, service, scheduled-tasks

I need to be able to generate some type of Scheduling service within Windows Azure, but which is the best and most resilient?

Currently I have a Windows Service running Quartz, which works okay, but on a Windows Server.  I need this to run in the cloud.

The tasks, read/write to a database and some will send emails.

I've looked over all the possible solutions in Stack Overflow, but they appear to be old and not updated to the latests Azure Platform.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use Quartz in the cloud?

Comment: Anyone tried Aditi Cloud Services [http://www.aditicloud.com/gettingstarted](http://www.aditicloud.com/gettingstarted)

Comment: You should look at the Windows Azure Mobile Services Scheduler.

http://www.nickharris.net/2012/12/execute-scheduled-scripts-with-the-new-windows-azure-mobile-services-scheduler/

Comment: Thanks Neil, just what I was after and more :-)

Comment: Have you tried cloud scheduling services such as http://atrigger.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Azure Mobile service and the Scheduler that come with it, which works a treat

Answer (score 0):

The most adapted solution might be a worker role, MS has a tutorial specifically for what you're looking for: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/4-worker-role-a/

This would definitely a less expensive solution than instantiating a virtual machine, but might require some work.

Answer (score 0):

I run a Worker Role using Quartz .NET to schedule stuff. Works great!
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet

Comment: Yes I've got this working too.  The Mobile Azure Scheduler is Zero code and easy to maintain.

Answer (score -4):

Obviously, that would be difficult to do on the cloud since you won't be able to install services or anything that could run in the background.  A less than perfect solution would be to have a workstation under your control handle the scheduling and send updates to the web server which would then write them to the DB server.  Otherwise, you should self host the website and application, etc.

Comment: This is PLAIN WRONG. Of course you can install background services if you want to. In "Cloud Services" you could do that through Start Up tasks while with "Virtual Machines" you could just RDP into your box and install whatever you want. However in cloud services, there's a concept of Worker Role which is meant to run background tasks.